# ¿Cómo generar PDF con variables de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql, php7

Les cuento que estoy trabajando en un sistema web que utiliza `PHP` y `MYSQL` con las siguientes tablas:

`cuestionario_respuestas`

```
id  |  pin  |  r1  |  r2  |  r3  |  r4  |
 1    BCNF     Si     No     Si     Si
 2    BCNF     No     No     Si     No
 3    BCNF     Si     No     No     Si
 4    XCNG     Si     No     Si     Si
```

`usuarios_registrados`

```
id  |   pin   |  nombre  |    email       |   contraseña  |
 1      BCNF      Juan     juan@mail.com       ********
 2      XCNG      Ana       ana@mail.com       ********
```

Una vez que el usuario inicia sesión con usuario y contraseña se encuentra con un botón que le permite generar un reporte **PDF** de las respuestas almacenadas en la tabla `cuestionarios_respuestas`, **pero me gustaría que lo hiciera de acuerdo al PIN que le corresponde** es decir, que si al usuario logueado le corresponde el PIN "BCNF", sólo le genere el **PDF** de esas respuestas "BCNF".

Para el login manejo el siguiente código:

```
  require 'database.php';
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

   $query = "SELECT pin FROM 
   usuarios_registrados where email = '$email' and password = '$password'";

  $bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
  $parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($bdconect) > 0){
  $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $parametros['nombre'];
  header("location: ../panel.php");
  }else {
   echo'<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
   window.location.href="../login.php";
   </script>';
   }
   ?>
```

Tengo el siguiente código para generar los reportes **PDF**, pero hasta el momento genera todo lo contenido en la tabla `cuestionarios_respuestas`.

`generarPDF.php`

```
<?php  
session_start();
function fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cuestionario_respuestas ORDER BY pin ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{      
    $output .= '
       <h2>Reporte Cuestionario</h2>
       <b>PIN:'.$row["pin"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 1:'.$row["r1"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 2:'.$row["r2"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 3:'.$row["r3"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 4:'.$row["r4"].'</b>;
}  
return $output;  
}  
if(isset($_POST["generate_pdf"]))  
{  
require_once('TCPDF-master/tcpdf.php');  
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);   
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
$obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
$obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');  
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '10', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
$obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
$obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);  
$obj_pdf->AddPage();  
$content = '';  
$content .= "";  
$content .= fetch_data();  

$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
$obj_pdf->Output('Reporte de Cuestionarios.pdf', 'I');  
}  
?>
```

Comment: Según lo que veo el pin te está presente en 3 filas distintas, por tanto cuando lo consultas, devuelve esas 3 lineas, por lo que `$row` tendría que recorrer esas filas también indicando la posición `$row[0]['pin']`

Comment: Si en efecto, el pdf se crea de manera correcta con la información de la tabla, pero quiero que se genere con las respuestas únicamente que corresponden al usuario que se logueo. Por ejemplo del id 1 al 3 nada más para el usuario con pin BCNF.

Comment: Listo, revisa la respuesta a ver sí te sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es cambiar la consulta en el archivo `generarPDF.php` ya que estás haciendo la consulta de todos los datos de la tabla, al igual que cuando haces el login debes guardar el pin en una variable `session` de la persona que ingresó  por lo tanto quedaría algo así:

`login`

```
require 'database.php';
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];

   $query = "SELECT * FROM 
   usuarios_registrados where email = '$email' and password = '$password'"; //Dejas el '*' porque necesitas traer todos los datos y cuando pones solamente 'pin' le dices que solamente te traiga ese campo, por lo tanto cuando usas $parametros['nombre'] no estaría llegando

  $bdconect = mysqli_query($conectar,$query);
  $parametros = mysqli_fetch_array($bdconect);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($bdconect) > 0){
  $_SESSION['username'] = $email;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $parametros['nombre'];
  $_SESSION['pin'] = $parametros['pin'];
  header("location: ../panel.php");
  }else {
   echo'<script type="text/javascript">
   alert("Usuario y/o Contraseña Incorrecos");
   window.location.href="../login.php";
   </script>';
   }
   ?>
```

Y ya en el `generarPDF.php` se llama esa variable para hacer la consulta, algo así:

```
?php  
session_start();
function fetch_data()  
{  
$output = '';  
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydbname"); 
$conn -> set_charset("utf8"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cuestionario_respuestas WHERE pin = '{$_SESSION['pin']}' ORDER BY pin ASC";  
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{      
    $output .= '
       <h2>Reporte Cuestionario</h2>
       <b>PIN:'.$row["pin"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 1:'.$row["r1"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 2:'.$row["r2"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 3:'.$row["r3"].'</b>
       <b>Respuesta 4:'.$row["r4"].'</b>;
}  
return $output;
```

Espero que te sirva, alguna duda o sugerencia me la comentas, saludos!

Comment: Esto me ha servido a la perfección, muchas gracias amigo @DaxTter77

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido, con gusto, para eso estamos, suerte con tu proyecto!